# Number of weight-balanced nodes in binary tree

Tags: binary-trees

I have to show that a binary tree with $n$ nodes has at least $(n-1)/2$ weight-balanced nodes and at most $n-1$ weight-balanced nodes. Here a node is *weight-balanced* if its siblings satisfy $\operatorname{weight}(u) \leq 2\operatorname{weight}(v)$.

So we get at least $(n-1)/2$ (where $n$ is positive and odd) if the one sibling satisfies $\operatorname{weight}(u)≤2\operatorname{weight}(v)$ and the other one doesn't (i.e. half of them when we disregard the root node).

And we get at most $n-1$ if both siblings satisfy $\operatorname{weight}(u)≤2\operatorname{weight}(v)$, so all nodes are weight-balanced except for the root node.

But how can I formally show that?

Comment: *a node is weight balanced if for siblings* $u$ *and* $v$ $weight(v) \le 2 weight(u) \le 4 weight(v)$ depends on definition: make it one.

Comment: I don't understand the definition of *weight-balanced*. I'm afraid it might be a linguistic issue.